# toggling using chevron icon in angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, icons, toggle

I have the below piece of code . I am trying to display the content using chevron up and down icons. The problem is that initially the icon doesnt show . Only when i click on that button the icon is shown and the functionality works.

I am not sure y the icon is not displayed initially for the first time .

```
<div class="item" >SKILLS
    <button class="button icon-right" ng-class="{'ion-chevron-up': skillsController.collapsed==false, 'ion-chevron-down': skillsController.collapsed==true}" ng-click="skillsController.collapsed=!skillsController.collapsed"></button>
</div>
<span class="item" ng-if="skillsController.collapsed==false">{{data.profileSummary}}</span>
```

Comment: At a guess, `skillsController.collapsed != false`, but without a [mcve] it's hard to offer more than that. It's `undefined`, maybe?

Comment: you have mentioned `angular` while code looks like `angularjs v1`. which is it?

Answer (score 0):

As a quick test, change

```
skillsController.collapsed==false
```

to

```
!skillsController.collapsed
```

If this variable is initially uninitialized, as suggested in by the behavior, the button should work with that syntax (provided skillsController itself is initialized).

I'd recommend initializing the variable anyway, as it will make your program more predictable.

Comment: Which variable should i initialize ? Should i do that in controller

Comment: If possible, initialize the one the icon display depends on - `skillsController.collapsed` (I realize that's a property of a variable, but same  principle).

Comment: In any case, what was the outcome of the test?

Comment: I still face the issue with !skillsController.collapsed

Comment: Well, that's a shame, no quick fix. You'll have to post more code.